# Extra blank lines added to some text files from Apache/PHP server on macOS

Tags: apache-http-server, php, macos-mojave

I have migrated from a server running macOS El Capitan/Server 5.2
to one using macOS Mojave/Apache 2.4.34 /PHP 7.1.23.

Certain text files are being served with extra blank lines after every line of text e.g. http://www.chemtube3d.com/model/Xiaohang-Qiao/Core/a_icosahedron/a.sdf

This prevents the files from being processed correctly.

```
M0001
  Spartan 03301710553D

 12 30  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0999 V2000
    3.3320  -25.2950  -12.2430 Au  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   15.5560  -32.0600   -3.2730 Au  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   11.7750  -24.5530   -0.9630 Au  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

becomes

```
M0001

  Spartan 03301710553D



 12 30  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0999 V2000

    3.3320  -25.2950  -12.2430 Au  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0

   15.5560  -32.0600   -3.2730 Au  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0

   11.7750  -24.5530   -0.9630 Au  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

I presume this is a problem with the configuration. Any advice would be welcome.

Comment: Have you checked the line endings are correct?

Comment: The file has not changed. You can check the line endings from the URL. I'm not sure what to look for.

Comment: Not a solution per se, but your example document *appears* to be served with CRLF (Windows) line endings. Mac only uses CR (and Unix only LF). I believe it is possible to change the default line endings in PHP. That said, if this was a file not generated by PHP, you would need to change the endings manually (e.g. in a text editor). Also, the difference in spacing may be a particular program interpreting CR and LF separately as new lines.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Almost all the files in the site were generated on macOS but, as you say, this one and a few others were created on Windows. I think the Windows line endings must have been interpreted incorrectly somewhere along the way. Is there a way to search for the CRLF (Windows) line endings?